# Handling form data and adding it to agGrid

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I have a page that contains a modal with a form. One of the elements on the form is an ag-grid where it saves each row as an array of objects and then passes that back to another grid on the original page. When sending the data back it continues to not display the array of objects correctly in the original page grid. I'm receiving a [Object object] is not valid JSON.

This is how the data is being put together for passing back to the original grid.

```
newParameters = [];

$dashboardParametersGrid.api.forEachNode((rowNode, index) => {

    if (rowNode.data.table && rowNode.data.column && rowNode.data.columnValue) {

        var parameter = {table: rowNode.data.table, column: rowNode.data.column, columnValue: rowNode.data.columnValue};

        JSON.stringify(parameter);

        newParameters.push(parameter);

    }

});

let client = {};
console.log(newParameters);
client['parameters'] = newParameters;
```

I'm tried `client['parameters'] = JSON.parse(newParameters)` and `client['parameters'] = JSON.stringify(newParameters)`.